# Does Lucene.Net allow searching and indexing at the same time?

Tags: wpf, lucene.net

When my collection of files is updated then I want to search the newest data...

Like windows Advance search option.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Does_Lucene_allow_searching_and_indexing_simultaneously.3F):

> **Does Lucene allow searching and indexing simultaneously?**
>
> Yes. However, an IndexReader only searches the index as of the "point in time" that it was opened. Any updates to the index, either added or deleted documents, will not be visible until the IndexReader is re-opened. So your application must periodically re-open its IndexReaders to see the latest updates. The IndexReader.isCurrent() method allows you to test whether any updates have occurred to the index since your IndexReader was opened.

Admittedly that's a reference to the Java version, but I'd expect the .NET version to work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The book, "Lucene in Action, Second edition" has a section on near real-time searching.  Basically, you get the IndexReader by calling the IndexWriter.GetReader() method and save it.  When starting a search, call the IndexWriter.GetReader() and compare the returned reader with the saved value.  If it is the same, just use the existing reader.  Multiple threads can share the same reader.

If it is different, close the old reader and save the new one.  Use the saved value for the search.

Behind the scene, the new reader includes all the pending (uncommitted) documents in the index.  Pending changes are flushed to disk (or RamDirectory), but not committed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search and index at the same time. The only thing you need to consider is that when you open your `IndexReader`, it basically takes a "snapshot" of the index: you need to close and reopen the `IndexReader` to get any new updates (or call `reopen`, which can be somewhat faster than closing and reopening).

Comment: Yes, all optimize does is rearrange the files on disk for faster access. It doesn't change the "logical" layout of your index in any way.